# Is there hidden data in this .blend file? Trying to minimize the file size

Tags: mesh, blend-files

I have this .blend file of a beard, and I'm trying to minimize the file size. I reduced the number of vertices from 30,718 to 88, but the file size only went from ~18MB to ~10MB. I can't figure out what the other data might be.

I have other files with more vertices/objects/materials that are only about 1MB, so it sure seems like something is hidden (at least from my inadequate eyes).

The file:
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. There are three packed jpg files.

Go to UV editor, select the first one, then click on the X button near its name, while holding the shift key.

Repeat this for the second and the third one, then save this file again.

A "0" will appear near the deleted images.

[image]

Comment: Alternatively *File> External Data> Unpack All Into Files* to at least unpack them.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. To maximize my learning, did you just think to look here through experience? Or was there some systematic way you found where data was being stored?

Comment: If you open a new Blender, then click on File>Append and browse in your file, you will see what it contains.

Comment: In addition to what FFeller said, you can look in the Outliner, where at the top it says All Scenes; change it to Blender File and you'll see what's in it.